# Use a variable ftp server hyperlink

Tags: vb.net, hyperlink, ftp

Today I have a (supposed) simple question: How can I upload a file to a ftp server with a variable hyperlink in VB.net?

I know the function

```
My.Computer.Network.UploadFile("ftp://webserver/filename", filepath, UserName, Password)
```

works very well and that's not the issue. However, when I try somethin like:

```
My.Computer.Network.UploadFile("ftp://webserver/" & SomeString, filepath, UserName, Password)
```

I get a `System.NotSupportedException` because the format is not supported.

How can I solve this? And, as always, thank you all in advance.

Comment: Could you define filename seperately as shown `Dim filename As String  = "ftp://webserver/" & SomeString` and try calling it?

Comment: No! I tried and it gave me the same error... Good thought tho...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong on your side. You just want something, that is not supported by that FTP server or .NET Framework itself. For more details look at exception's message.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my... I made a stupid thing... I put the arguments in a wrong order. Actually it does work fine :)

```
My.Computer.Network.UploadFile(filepath, "ftp://webserver/" & SomeString, UserName, Password)
```

Sorry you guys... :(